# Square of a probability is the same

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation

In proof of Chebyshev Inequality, I read Pr[ |X − a| ≥ t] = Pr[(X − a)^2 ≥ t^2]. But I don't quite get how. May someone explains to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement requires that $t\ge 0.$ It is then true since $x^2 \ge t^2$ is equivalent to $|x| > t,$ as can be seen by looking at the cases of positive and negative $x$ separately.

It $t$ is negative, say $t=-1$, then $1/2 \ge t,$ but not $(1/2)^2 \ge t^2.$